# to pass prameter value with double quotes in flutter -

Tags: api, flutter, post, quotes

i am passing parameter value like this -

```
'HomeTown': '"' + homeTownPerm + '"',
```

but its not taking with quotes these values any solution for this -

Comment: yes, it is: `var town = 'Rome';
var res = '"' + town + '"';
print(town);
print(res);`

Comment: you can simply use a '\' if you want to add double or single quotes or dollar sign inside a string : Above string can be written as : "HomeTown \" $homeTownPerm \" "

Comment: just to add parenthesis with value

Comment: "email " like this and its printing like this now

Comment: i am lost, so what is the problem?

Comment: there no problem with this approach -  var town = 'Rome'; var res = '"' + town + '"'; print(town); print(res); – its working now.

Comment: but i did not change anything: this is your original code!

Comment: yes may be i didn't notice that before.